# Substitution command in neovim remaps not working

Tags: neovim

I simply want to map < leader> pu to erase all occurrences of the carriage return character
(represented as ^M) in a file.

I can execute the command:

```
:%s/\r//g
```

and it works.

Any attempts to use vim.keymap.set in my remap.lua file, however, error out when I try to source it.

Attempts include:

```
vim.keymap.set('n', '<leader>pu', vim.cmd('%s/\r//g'))
```

Errors with "Pattern not found:"
using square brackets errors with "Pattern not found:\r"

```
vim.keymap.set('n', '<leader>pu', vim.cmd.substitute{ range = '%', args = {'\r',''} })
```

Errors with " Invalid command arg: expected non-whitespace"

An attempt with a different character, 'r', sources, but applies the command inside the sourced file instead of mapping it.

```
vim.keymap.set('n', '<leader>pu', vim.cmd('%s/r//g'))
```

I have other mappings using vim.cmd that work fine, and do not apply in the remap file.

Maybe this is a skill issue, but I need some assistance.

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

```
vim.api.nvim_set_keymap('n', '<leader>pu', ':%s/\\r//<CR>', {})
```

credit here:
https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/42622/substitution-command-in-neovim-remaps-not-working